# Unlock event iPhone

Tags: iphone, events, unlock

Does anybody know if there is an xcode unlock event that can track if somebody unlocks his iPhone?

Or is this only possible with jailbroken devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is: NO, that's not possible!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this on a non-jailbroken device using `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver`.

Add an observer for the Darwin notification 'lockstate':

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), 
                            NULL, 
                            lockStateDidNotify, 
                            CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.lockstate"),
                            NULL, 
                            CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

and you will be notified each time the device locks/unlocks:

```
static void lockStateDidNotify(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo) 
{
    NSLog(@"The Device Locked/Unlocked");
}
```

Since this fires for both a lock and an unlock it is not entirely what you want, but you can observe `com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete` (which **only** fires during a lock) and check to see if you get both. If you don't get the `lockcomplete` you can assume an unlock just happened.

Comment: These darwin notifications are private API and hence apple rejects apps using them. Is there any public APIs to do this?